# Locate matching values in different XLS sheets and copy other cell values from matching row

Tags: excel-2007, excel, excel-formula, vba

Sheet1 column B contains my customer number- I need to locate this customer number in Sheet2 column F.  Then copy the value from Sheet2 AE (from the row with the matching customer number) into the matching customer number row in Sheet1 column E.  Note that sheet1 column B and Sheet2 column F contain the same customer numbers, but not in the same order and sorting is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

So, after much trial and error I worked out the perfect solution!  Thought I'd share just in case anyone else is trying to do the same.

I entered the following into column E:

```
=INDEX(sheet2!$AE$4:$AE$10000,MATCH(B4,sheet2!$F$4:$F$10000,FALSE)*1)
```